# How to add background img in wordpress3.5.1

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, background-image, background-color

How can I add a background image or color to my Wordpress 3.5.1?
My Wordpress theme doesn't have "background" in the  Appearance widget in my Wordpress dashboard.

Comment: what about appearence>themes>customise don't you get get the background option even there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use multiple solutions for that. I will give 2 sollutions.

1. In your file .css set the backround-color like this:

   `.body{
   background:#000000;
   }`
2. You can use a class to handle that:

   `.backround {
   position:absolute;
   backround:#000000;//or, instead #000000; use url(path_to_image);
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: 999; 
    min-height: 30px;
    left:0;
    padding-top:10px;
   }`

This is it!